# Check if the external js file is already loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, getscript

On success of ajax request, i load a script using,

```
$.getScript(base_url + 'js/js_to_be_loaded.js');
```

Is there any way i could check if that particular script is already loaded ?

Thanks.

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) ;)

Comment: I know neither javascript, nor jquery so good to say if it has built-in method to check one. You can have variable `var x = 0;` increment one when you load your `js` and before loading script, check if `x==0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need only to implement a `success` callback function.

```
jQuery.getScript( url [, success(script, textStatus, jqXHR)] )
```

like:

```
$.getScript(base_url + 'js/js_to_be_loaded.js', onSuccess);

function onSuccess(...)
{
    // in this function you are guaranteed that it is loaded
    // so you can execute code based on the loaded js file or
    // set flags to let your code "know" that it is loaded
}
```